# Play in Quarq power meter on a Trek emonda

Tags: crankset, threaded-bottom-bracket

I am currently installing a Quarq d four power meter on my ‘22 Trek emonda and have been having some issues. I purchased the sram dub t47 85.5 wide bottom bracket to work with the new crankset. The bb came with two spacers, 2.5 and 5 mm, which have been installed based on srams compatibility page.

When tightening the the spindle to the arm, there is a little play. It feels like the arms can rotate just slightly when I pedal. By this I mean that can actually wiggle the arms back in forth. I have the preload adjustment all the way backed off and cannot tighten it at all.

My first question would be if I got the right bottom bracket? As far as I can tell the Emonda uses a 85.5 wide rather than the non wide version. The non wide is set up with a 3 mm spacer on one side which seems like it would take up a lot of that play.

Second, if you know of any solution please let me know. I am very confused and feel like I’m so close but just slightly off.

Thanks you for your time.